# Question on lines of regression

Tags: probability, statistics, regression, linear-regression, regression-analysis

[image]

I know how to find the line of regression when given the set of values of x and y. But in this question i don't have any idea what to do.

I am a beginner . I will really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $b_{yx}=\dfrac{1}{7}$ and $b_{xy}=c$. On using the property of the regression coefficients 
\begin{eqnarray*}
r^2 &=& b_{yx}\times b_{xy}\\
&=& \left(\dfrac{1}{7}\right)c\\
c &=& 7\cdot r^{2}
\end{eqnarray*}
As $r^2$ lies between 0 and 1, hence, $0\leq c \leq 7$.